# Выполнение процедуры в отдельном контексте

Tags: многопоточность, ассемблер

Запускается несколько потоков, в каждом выполняется вызов процедуры из внещнего модуля.
Возможно ли выполнение этой процедуры в контексте этого потока?

Пример..

Procedure Thread.Work;

asm

call [Proc]  <--

end;

Answer (score 0):

Ну как задан вопрос - да, возможно.

**Код** может выполняться в любом потоке, нужно только обеспечить синхронизацию доступа к **данным**.

Если же в этой процедуре уже заложена работа с данными без учёта многопоточности, то проблемы будут.